# What's the name of the type of expansion set "packs" that MTG players can buy at release events?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I've heard that MTG vendors can have release events for expansion sets.  During these events, players can spend a relatively small amount (say, $20 bucks) and get a collection of cards from that set (enough to build a deck or two).

What is the name for these value sets?  It seems like they're somewhere between a booster pack and a booster box in size. Can they only be purchased at release events?

Answer (score 4):

The format of the pre-release and release party events is a tournament type called 'sealed deck' where you get 6 packs of cards to make a 40 card deck out of.

For recent sets wizards has been printing special "event packs" where one or two of the six boosters you get is custom tailored to a specific colour, colour combo, or deck archetype.  This is to make it easier for new players to build a half-decent deck, since looking at 6 totally random packs and figuring out which two or three colors are best takes some practiced skill!

It comes in a little box with a spindown d20 life counter also.  I think this is probably the product you're talking about.  Some event hosts will sell leftovers after the tournament.  As far as I know this doesn't violate any of their distribution agreements with WOTC.

This is a description of the most recent one:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160115045141/http://archive.wizards.com:80/Magic/tcg/events.aspx?x=mtgcom/events/prerelease-facts)

Comment: Theros Block sets had one color-seeded pack, Dragon's Maze had *two* seeded packs that were the colors of allied guilds, and M14 didn't have a seeded pack at all. Maro from Wizards said that M14 would be the last prerelease without some sort of extra gimmick. Also, store owners can definitely sell leftovers, and they can order more and even run another event using them (after the actual release of course).